# How to graph log functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you graph $y=\log_2(x-3)+4$? I know that $(h,k)$ are $(3,4)$ but i do not know the critical points, domain, range, and asymptote, help please!

Comment: What do you mean by $(h,k)$? 
You know that $\operatorname{log}_b(x)$ is defined only for positive $x$.  For points, choose ones that make it easy for you to evaluate the function; i.e., $x - 3 = 2^k$ for integers $k$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We obtain the domain and the asymptote from the inequality $x-3 > 0$. 
In this case, the domain is $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x>4$ and the asymptote is $x=3$.

Range will be $\mathbb{R}$ since we can make the function as arbitrarily small or as arbitrarily large by taking different values close and far away from x =3.

There are no critical points since the slope of the function is never $0$.

Also the function will have a vertical displacement of 4